# Horizontal scrolling/sliding menu for dynamic width

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need a sliding horizontal menu which can slide left & right in case menu has more items.

I have set up example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZRaee) with the horizontal menu. This menu is fine is i have 4 items and if i add 5th or 6th item then other menu items are not visible.

How can i add slide left or right feature so that user can slide right to see the other menu items. We have similar menu for Android or IOS apps. Is there anything similar for HTML version.

How can i work around this code to make it work.

[image]

HTML SOURCE

```
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">MenuONE</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">MTWO</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">MenuFIVE</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c">
    <p>This is ONE.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2-c">
    <p>This is TWO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab3-c">
    <p>This is THREE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab4-c">
    <p>This is FOUR</p>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: You could go for slider type effect. The carousel is what i am talking about not for images but for your menu-items.

Comment: I tried wrap the ul inside another div and gave this dive overflow-x:scroll, but the scrollbar will show.. I was working around this but didnt work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwNqEo?editors=1100

Comment: @divy3993, I have thought of that also but i have not tried as i have to look which carousal to use in this case..

Comment: May be this will also work http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/itemsCustom.html

Answer (score 0):

Use This code 
use in li display: table-cell;..

```js
 $('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){ 
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
 $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();  
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.tab-container {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper {
  width: 360px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.current-tab {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.tab1-c,
.tab2-c,
.tab3-c,
.tab4-c,
.tab5-c {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content-wrapper {
  width: 360px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper > ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
      display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -5px !important;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper > ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 20%;
  background: #006097;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 40%;
  background: #f18b2d;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 60%;
  background: #683177;
}

.five:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 80%;
  background: #ffd100;
}
.six:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper > ul hr {
  height: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #00a0df;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  float: left;
}

a.active {
  color: #000;
}
ul
{
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">MenuONE</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">MTWO</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">MenuFIVE</a></li>
    <li class="six"><a href="#">MenuSIX</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c">
    <p>This is ONE.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab2-c">
    <p>This is TWO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab3-c">
    <p>This is THREE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab4-c">
    <p>This is FOUR</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab5-c">
    <p>This is FOUR</p>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: I tried same thing but i dont want to show scrollbar it should work when we swipe left or right for mobile phones etc.. This is where i am struggling.